# ASP.net : Simple way to add glyphs to website for sharing on social networking

Tags: asp.net

I want to add the glyphs for popular social netowrking sites like FB, twitter, digg, buzz to my website. I have looked into AddThis and ShareThis sharing widgets. However, I want to do the same thing on my own without these 3rd party tools. 
I have master page and to it I want to add these glyphs like Like from FB. I am confused..in order for the like to work for each page how do i keep track of the like counter... How to do it for twitter and all popular sites.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of the like counter"?  Do you want to add the _actual_ Facebook Like button to like the site on Facebook, or do you just want to copy the functionality and keep an internal count of how many people clicked on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I used AddThis add on and it seems easy to customize than ShareThis widget... AddThis forum is also very helpful...Now all the integeration headache is for AddThis to resolve and I am left at peace.

Answer (score 1):

Each target site is going to have its own API and its own methods for adding things.  As an example, the Like button for Facebook can be quickly added to your site by generating the XFBML or iFrame code for the button [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

If you go the XFBML route, which gives you more flexibility (I inferred from your comment about not relying on 3rd party libraries that this is your intent), then you'll need to include the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

The "count" of how many people "like" your site (or your application, if you register it as a Facebook application for even more flexibility) is tracked by Facebook.  You don't need to track it.  But you *can* if you want by [adding custom code to the right JavaScript event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) (mentioned in the FAQ on my first link).

Comment: Thanks for ur input. For the website, for each page i want a FB like button..which should show the counter for each page and not one FB like button for the whole website. e.g. for my hypothetical website xyz.com .. i have pages like xyz.com/promotions.aspx, xyz.com/tickets.aspx, xyz.com/sales.com, xyz.com/gifts.com.... all these .aspx pages have a single master page. Now I want to have FB like button on each page..and it should show 23 people like promotions.aspx, 40 people like gifts.com and not just 1 counter 80 people like xyz.com. There must be a better way to link like button for each pag

Comment: @shazia: Well, if you want each page to have its own unique button, then you're definitely going to have to add one to each page.  I'm not sure what the Facebook terms and conditions are regarding that.  But I was able to generate a Like button using the linked form for a specific page within my site.  Your best bet is to test it and see how it behaves.  You may need to register each page as its own application on Facebook, which may be a problem.

Comment: @David thanks again..u got me rt this time... lot of websites like newspapers have new pages everyday and they include these fb plugin... I doubt it that they create a new page for whole bunch of articles everyday... surely there must be a better nd earsier way

Comment: @shazia: Do they include the button for each individual dynamic content item, or for the site in general?  Do you have an example of the former?

Comment: @david : you can check out bbc.com, they have it for each page and it displays the share counter, FB like and twitter counters for each page and not for the whole site.

Comment: @shazia: I don't see any Facebook "like" buttons on the story pages there.  I do see a custom "share" functionality, but it looks like they're tracking that internally.  They likely have a single registered Facebook application which just shares the link on the user's wall.  The actual counting is handled internally by the site (well, they may use a 3rd party, but you can do it internally).  For that you'd just increment an integer on a given event (such as when the user clicks the share link, or in response to an event from the Facebook API after a successful post).

Comment: @shazia: So I guess the overall technical approach would be to make an AJAX call to a back-end resource to increment the integer.  That way you track the total count on the server-side.  In response to the successful AJAX call, you can also increment the integer on the client-side.  (Additionally, the response could contain the current total and you can up the client-side count to that, in the event that multiple people share the link during the page life cycle.)